# Solving second order differential equation with finite difference method (boundary conditions)

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-difference-methods

Hello I am trying to solve this second order differential equation:

$$r\frac{d^{2}y}{dr^{2}}+\frac{dy}{dr}=0$$

where $0\le r\le 1$, with the following boundary conditions:

$$r=0, y=200$$
$$r=1, y=36$$
$$c\frac{dy}{dr} = \beta(y-y_{b}), r=1$$

where c and beta are constants.
For the outer boundary, the discretization is (only for the outer boundary):

$$\frac{dy}{dr}=\frac{3y_{n}-4y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}}{2h}, (r_{n}=1)$$

I want to use finite difference method to solve this problem. I have tried to use central differences of the second and first derivatives with the following forumlas:

$$f′(x)≈\frac{f(x+h)−f(x−h)}{2h}$$
$$f''(x)≈\frac{f(x-h)−2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^{2}}$$

When inserting in the differential equation I get:

$$(r-\frac{h}{2})y_{j-1}-(2r)y_{j}+(r+\frac{h}{2})y_{j+1} = 0$$

and when inserting j=1 and using the initial boundary conditions I get:

$$-(2r)y_{1}+(r+\frac{h}{2})y_{2} = -(r-\frac{h}{2})*200$$

and for the outer boundary condition I get:

$$\frac{1}{2h}y_{j-2}+(\frac{r}{h^{2}}-\frac{4}{2h})y_{j-1}+(\frac{3}{2h}-\frac{2r}{h^{}})y_{j}+(\frac{r}{h^{}})y_{j+1}=0$$

but then I don't know what to do next. I am not sure if my calculations are right because I get zeros on the right hand vector (except for the boundaries) which seems strange. Can someone please help me and see where I have gone wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you can impose 3 boundary conditions in a second order differential equation?

Comment: What do you mean? I just stated what information is given for the problem.

Comment: I mean that setting the value of $y$ at $r=0$ and  $r=1$ fixes the solution... You cannot enforce the first boundary condition.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The conditions $y(0)=200$ and $y(1)=36$ are enough to determine the solution. So, the third condition, $c y'(r) = \beta (y-y_b)$ at $r=1$ cannot be imposed: either it is satisfied (by mere chance) or the problem has no solution.

Comment: The singularity at $r=0$ reduces the number of available boundary conditions to 1. There are only constant solutions that are finite at $r=0$.